# Usergrid requests queing

Tags: java, cassandra, usergrid

I've started to check USERGRID as front+back end solution for my last project. Actually, I'm focused on evaluating the performance of this framework. I couldn't find any information about the treatment of the REST requests arriving to the server. Are they queued? If yes, can its capacity be configured?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Requests are not queued.  They are processed in realtime as they arrive.  We are working on a new entity manager, which will post process batch processes asynchronously.